# I'm unable to display the button

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
answer=StringVar()
disp=Entry(root,bg="blue",font=("bold",20),bd=20,textvariable= answer).grid(row=0,columnspan=4)
btn1=Button(root,text="1",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=1,column=0)
btn2=Button(root,text="2",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=1,column=1)
btn3=Button(root,text="3",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=1,column=2)
btn4=Button(root,text="4",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=2,column=0)
btn5=Button(root,text="5",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=2,column=1)
btn6=Button(root,text="6",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=2,column=2)
btn7=Button(root,text="7",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=3,column=0)
btn8=Button(root,text="8",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=3,column=1)
btn9=Button(root,text="9",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=3,column=2)
btn0=Button(root,text="0",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=4,column=2)
btn_add=Button(root,text="+",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=1,column=3)
btn_sub=Button(root,text="-",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=2,column=3)
btn_mul=Button(root,text="x",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=3,column=3)
btn_div=Button(root,text="%",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=4,column=0)
btn_equl=Button(root,text="=",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=4,column=1)
btn_clr=Button(root,text="CLR",padx=10,bg="white",fg="black",font=("bold",20)).grid(row=4,column=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code produces errors. If it's indicative of your actual code, please include the error in your question. Also, a good [mcve] for this question only requires a single button. Once you learn how to do one, you'll be able to do 16.

Answer (score 1):

`column` instead of `coloumn`,`columnspan` instead of `coloumnspan`

Answer (score 1):

This will work just use `column` instead of `coloumn` and `coloumnspan` instead of `columnspan`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
answer = StringVar()
disp = Entry(root, bg="blue", font=("bold", 20), bd=20, textvariable=answer).grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
btn1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=1, column=0)
btn2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=1, column=1)
btn3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=1, column=2)
btn4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=2, column=0)
btn5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=2, column=1)
btn6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=2, column=2)
btn7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=3, column=0)
btn8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=3, column=1)
btn9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=3, column=2)
btn0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=4, column=2)
btn_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=1, column=3)
btn_sub = Button(root, text="-", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=2, column=3)
btn_mul = Button(root, text="x", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=3, column=3)
btn_div = Button(root, text="%", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=4, column=0)
btn_equl = Button(root, text="=", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=4, column=1)
btn_clr = Button(root, text="CLR", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20)).grid(row=4, column=3)
root.mainloop()
```

I always prefer doing it in a two-step manner like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

answer = StringVar()

disp = Entry(root, bg="blue", font=("bold", 20), bd=20, textvariable=answer)
btn1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_sub = Button(root, text="-", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_mul = Button(root, text="x", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_div = Button(root, text="%", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_equl = Button(root, text="=", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))
btn_clr = Button(root, text="CLR", padx=10, bg="white", fg="black", font=("bold", 20))

disp.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2)
btn4.grid(row=2, column=0)
btn5.grid(row=2, column=1)
btn6.grid(row=2, column=2)
btn7.grid(row=3, column=0)
btn8.grid(row=3, column=1)
btn9.grid(row=3, column=2)
btn0.grid(row=4, column=2)
btn_add.grid(row=1, column=3)
btn_sub.grid(row=2, column=3)
btn_mul.grid(row=3, column=3)
btn_div.grid(row=4, column=0)
btn_equl.grid(row=4, column=1)
btn_clr.grid(row=4, column=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: @ajith kumar  Please make sure to accept the answer if the code works.